# mapview not centring on current users location

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to centre the mapview on the users location but so far its not working. I've tried to test it on my physical device with no luck and I can't find a solution that works please help me.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

let distanceSpan: Double = 500

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupMapView()
}

fileprivate func setupLocationManager() {self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == true {

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .restricted || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .denied || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {

            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 1.0
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    } else {
        print("PLease turn on location services or GPS")
    }

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.002, longitudeDelta: 0.002))
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}

fileprivate func setupMapView() {
    let mView = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
    mView.showsUserLocation = true
    view.addSubview(mView)
    self.mapView = mView
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem even more please? Then I would be able to give you a better guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to update the camera on the new location.

Read [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory) for more information.

Basically you need to implamant the function CameraUpdate().